# USN upgrade offline

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I need to apply some USN upgrades to a system which is offline (not connected to internet)

My question is this :
For example i have an installed package named "libegl1-mesa:amd64 - 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.1" on the target server.
In the USN details on Ubuntu's page , it says that the package should be "libegl1-mesa-19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2" for it to be considered as "upgraded".

So the question is does the last part of the package name (18.04.1 vs 18.04.2) matter or i should only look at the package version itself (19.2.8) ?

Another question - Is it safe/possible to upgrade a "linux-image-x.x.x-xx-generic-x.x.x-xx.56~18.04.1" to a newer version without internet? By transferring the source code and compiling it..? (As i understand there is no deb for it)
Or you must have internet for this kind of upgrades?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it matters, the whole package name contains the patch. If you're using the 18.04.1 file, that means it doesn't include *backported* security fixes.  The initial part of the name is the package details; the last part contains clues as to security fixes enclosed. So if security matters, the last part of the package name for sure matters.  https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1/changelog

Comment: There are two independent, unrelated questions squished together here. These should be two separate Questions. Use the Search feature at the top of the page; neither question is new.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find an answer to my second question, i will post it as a new one.